# Are Ioun Stones considered an attended item for saving throws?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, saving-throw

After carefully reading the description of [Ioun Stones](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/), I am left wondering if they are suppose to be considered attended objects or not. This is of course for the free floating version, not ones that have been inserted into a wayfinder which would clearly be attended.

Reasons for why they could be considered unattended objects

- Item description does not directly mention they are attended

  > An ioun stone must be able to orbit freely around a creature’s head for its power to be active
- They have their own AC which I cant think of another attended object which has its own AC

Reasons for why they could be considered attended objects

- No listed saving throws for the purposes of AoE's which suggests they are suppose to use their owners

Overall there isnt any strong evidence in either category by my thoughts. Personally I would side with them being attended objects since that's how I have always treated them, and it was only recently that I considered otherwise.

Comment: Related: [Protecting Ioun Stones from theft and damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83439)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Ioun Stones orbit your head, they are considered attended and only suffer damage from AOEs when you roll a nat 1. If they are targeted directly, they use your save.

Quote From [D20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/#Facts_About_Ioun_Stones)

> An ioun stone in orbit counts as an attended object, and benefits from any magical protections possessed by its owner.

Fun Fact... You can also [Implant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/#Implanted_Ioun_Stones) them in your skin to make them immune from being targeted.

> Once implanted, an ioun stone may not be sundered or targeted by effects and cannot be removed without the owner’s consent while he is alive (barring complete removal of the implanted body part).

Comment: I have no idea of how I missed that line in the description. I thought I had been so careful in reading it.